# What is the format specifier of error_code?

Tags: c++, format-specifiers, cpprest-sdk

I'm trying to use **Microsoft's cpprestsdk**. And I was getting an error, and so I wanted to check the error code. But I'm not able to figure out the format specifier of `error_code`, and I'm getting this warning :

> warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3
>   has type ‘const std::error_code’ [-Wformat=]
>         printf("HTTP Exception :: %s\nCode :: %d\n", e.what(), e.error_code());

How should I print the error code? Although `%d` works but I wanted to know the actual specifier so that I won't get any warnings.

PS: I saw some of them here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75w45ekt(v=vs.120).aspx , but I don't think any of them are any help to me.

Comment: [`std::error_code`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_code) is a *class*. Of course you can't use it in the old C `printf` function. What is the reason you use `printf` to begin with?

Comment: Nothing, I was just wondering Is there a way to do it this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::error_code` is a class and can not be passed as printf argument. But you can pass an `int` value returned by `error_code::value()`.

Comment: They could also use `cout <<` to output it instead of `printf`

Comment: @NathanOliver I know I can, but there were conflicts with `namespace std` , so I thought of printf.

Comment: @NikhilWagh Don't use `using namespace std;`.  Just use `std::cout`

Answer (score 2):

here's one way:

```
#include <system_error>
#include <cstdio>

void emit(std::error_code ec)
{
    std::printf("error number: %d : message : %s : category : %s", ec.value(), ec.message().c_str(), ec.category().name());
}
```

But let's not use printf...

```
#include <system_error>
#include <iostream>

void emit(std::error_code ec)
{
    std::cout << "error number : " << ec.value()
              << " : message : " << ec.message() 
              << " : category : " << ec.category().name()
              << '\n';
}
```